# leaflet-omnivore style function

Tags: leaflet, topojson

Please pardon my ignorance in advance, but is it possible to style a layer(polygon) using the plugin leaflet-omnivore? All of the examples I've encountered are using the MapBox API

I have the layer rendering default colors with the following line, omnivore.topojson('./data/bmw_parcels_4326.json').addTo(map);

Something like the Leaflet tutorial example as follows would be nice. I just can't figure out how to call the function:

```
function getColor(d) {
    return d > 1000 ? '#800026' :
           d > 500  ? '#BD0026' :
           d > 200  ? '#E31A1C' :
           d > 100  ? '#FC4E2A' :
           d > 50   ? '#FD8D3C' :
           d > 20   ? '#FEB24C' :
           d > 10   ? '#FED976' :
                      '#FFEDA0';
}

function style(feature) {
return {
    fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.density),
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 1,
    color: 'white',
    dashArray: '3',
    fillOpacity: 0.7
};
}

L.geoJson(statesData, {style: style}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the documentation of Leaflet-omnivore here: https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore
You can pass a custom layer as a third parameter of omnivore.topojson(). By default, it is simply L.geoJson(). In your case, you should use something like this:

```
var customLayer = L.geoJson(null, {style: style});
omnivore.topojson('./data/bmw_parcels_4326.json', null, customLayer).addTo(map);
```

The other option is L.GeoJSON.setStyle(style) function called on your omnivore layer:

```
var layer = omnivore.topojson('./data/bmw_parcels_4326.json');
layer.setStyle(style);
layer.addTo(map);
```

Not tested, hope this helps.